# List[String] to query from List[String, Int], and sum the values of each row

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark

I have a series of List[String],

```
List(ejlo, adln, bew)
List(ejlo, alnw, bde)
List(dllo, aejn, bew)
List(dow, aejn, bell)
List(dell, ajno, bew)
```

Each word needs to be checked with a Map[String, (String, Int)] to get its value.

```
Map["ejlo", ("ejlo", 2)]
Map["bca", ("abc", 8)]
Map["ufi", ("iuf", 1)]
```

I need to get each row List[String] 's sum.

How can I do it?

**Update**,

Like first List(ejlo, adln, bew),

each string has corresponding Int value from a Map,

so now I need to foreach loop through each List row,

and, calling that Map("ejlo"), and it will return Int value 2,

Then, calling Map("adln"), and it will return an Int value n,

Then, calling Map("bew"), and it will return an Int value y,

And, I need the sum of 2 + n +y for this List row,

Eventually, I need to calculate each List row's sum,

And, find the lowest value, and return the given List row with the List String.

I am doing something like below, but I know its slow,

```
 var finalCircledFinalAns: List[String] = List()
    var scoredCounter: Int = 99999
    var counter: Int = 0
    var tempList = new ListBuffer[String]()

    for (elem <- CircledCombinations) {
      elem.foreach{ x =>
        counter  += filteredCircledMap(x).map(_._2).head
        tempList += filteredCircledMap(x).map(_._1).head
      }
      if (scoredCounter > counter) {
        finalCircledFinalAns = tempList.toList
        scoredCounter = counter
      }
      scoredCounter = 0
      tempList = new ListBuffer[String]()
    }
```

Thanks.

**Update**

```
CircledCombinations.foreach(println) // There are 50 rows return 
List(deen, allw, bjo)
List(abdl, ejlo, enw)
List(deew, abll, jno)
List(adej, blow, eln)

filteredCircledMap.foreach(println) // There are more than 60 rows return
(add,List((dad,4477)))
(aben,List((bean,6711)))
(elno,List((lone,9719)))
(aal,List((ala,8982)))
(dnow,List((down,310)))
(dlo,List((old,370)))
```

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by `List[String]`'s sum. Can you elaborate more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @nicodp I just update the post, please check it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you please provide what are `CircledCombinations` and `filteredCircledMap`?

Comment: @nicodp Hi, I just update the post. Please check it. Each string from CircledCombinations has a corresponding row matching from filteredCircledMap. For the format purpose, I just copy paste few rows here.

Comment: @nicodp The structure like this, Map[String, List(String, Int)), has it own reason, since the first String is the same as the second String.

Comment: My answer uses your type for the Map, check it up.

Comment: @nicodp I do have another quick question, if now I have a string and wants to get the charAt(), like 1, 4,5, And, maybe next String, I want to get charAt(), like 2, 3, 5, what's the best to get it and store as a new string? Thanks.

Comment: @nicodp In the filteredCircledMap, how can I conditionally add 10,000, if the Int value is 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163649/discussion-between-nicodp-and-jason).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your description, you need to traverse some kind of list of lists structure called `CircledCombinations`, and then you have a map called `filteredCircledMap` that serves as a mapping from strings to values of type int.

I'll assume `CircledCombinations` is a list of lists. Also, it's a bit weird your mapping: instead of being that obfuscated type it should be more simpler: `Map[String, Int]`.

What you could do instead of looping and think this problem in a OOP style, is to approach this in a more functional fashion likewise:

```
val scoresForEachRow: List[List[Int]] =
  CircledCombinations.map(_.map(filteredCircledMap(_).head._2))
```

That will give you, at least from what I got from your question, the calculated scores for every element of each row (values are invented by me):

```
List(
  List(2, 5, 4),
  List(5, 3, 1),
  // and so on...
)
```

And then, you can map the function `sum` to get every row sum likewise:

```
val sumForEachRow: List[Int] = scoresForEachRow.map(_.sum)
```

There, you will end up with this (the example above):

```
List(
  11,
  9,
  // and so on...
)
```

From here, you can calculate the minimum value by:

```
val minimumVal: Int = sumForEachRow.min
```

I think you need to address more things with the problem, but I reckon this will help you to give a first step to it. You can use `zip` to keep track of the strings if you want to do so.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to get also the actual list of strings that have the minimum (or maximum value) you can use `zip`:

```
val sumsAndLists: List[List[String], Int] =
  scoresForEachRow.zip(sumForEachRow)
```

And then, your desired result, using `minBy`:

```
val minimumAndList: (List[String], Int) = sumsAndLists.minBy(_._2)
```